# io-ts array type with minimum length?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

I have these two types defined (using `io-ts`):

```
export const School = t.type({
    _id: t.string,
    title: t.string,
    slug: t.string,
    images: t.array(ImageType),
});
export type School = t.TypeOf<typeof School>;

export const ImageType = t.intersection([
  t.type({
    url: t.string,
    width: t.number,
    height: t.number,
    lqip: t.string
  }),
  t.partial({
    hotspot: t.type({
      height: t.number,
      width: t.number,
      x: t.number,
      y: t.number
    })
  })
]);
export type ImageType = t.TypeOf<typeof ImageType>;
```

I wan't the array type for the images property to be an array of `ImageType`, but with a minimum length of 1. How can I achieve this?

So that I can validate response data, and know that I always safely can access `school.images[0].url`, without extra checking each time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate array length with io-ts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429769/how-to-validate-array-length-with-io-ts)

Comment: [NonEmptyArray](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/NonEmptyArray.ts.html). Please note that this type doesn't have several operations like `filter`, because such operations may return an empty structure.

Comment: @scriptum Is that so? I just wan't to be able validate incoming data, to make sure that there is at least one image, using `t.array(ImageType).deoce(images)`. But after that I wan't it to behave like a regular array. Is that not possible?

Comment: I don't know FP-TS' implementation, but usually if there is a `filter`/`take` combinator for an `NonEmpty` type it returns a normal `Array`/`List` to indicate the loss of the non-empty guarantee.

Comment: Ok, I'm wondering specifically about `fp-ts`. I don't think that would behave like that.